# When the state is set by search the filter options dont get populated (only single option is loaded) Tyescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, search, filtering, state-management

**REQUIREMENT:**
When a combination is selected it should populate below select components each select component has aparent which decides its option so they can give the list of items present in the list.

**PROBLEM:**
The filter works fine when it is used without search, when they are set using search component only the values that were in the search string appear(data list was not being generated)

**TRIED FIXES:**
used isSearch to set the filters which enabled the search to set the value on select component.
Tried to update  the state by separating filtering and the data to set.
tried adding use state and generating the datalist inside select.

**CODE:**

```
//Select component
import React, { useEffect, useId, useState } from "react"
import _ from "lodash"
import { FormControl, Select, InputLabel, MenuItem, SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material"
import ISelect from "@/types/select"

const SelectComponent: React.FC<ISelect> = (props) => {
const { val, label, keyVal, dataList, onChangeVal} = props
 const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>()
 const [value, setVal] = useState<any>("")
 const id = useId()

 useEffect(() => {
  setVal(val)
  console.log(val)
 }, [val])

 useEffect(() => {
   if (keyVal && dataList && dataList?.length > 0) {
     const _data = _.map(dataList, keyVal)
     console.log("data:",_data,"dataList:",dataList,"keyVal:",keyVal)
     setData(_data)
    } else {
      setData([])
    }
  }, [keyVal, dataList])
  
  useEffect(()=>{
   if(val && keyVal && onChangeVal && dataList && dataList.length > 0){
     setVal(val)
     onChangeVal(keyVal,val)
     console.log(val)
   }
  },[val])
 const handleChange = (e:string) => {
  const _val = e
  if (keyVal && onChangeVal) {
   setVal(_val)
   onChangeVal(keyVal, _val)
   console.log(dataList)
  }
 }
 useEffect(() => {
    if (keyVal && data && onChangeVal && data.length === 1) {
      setVal(data[0]);
      onChangeVal(keyVal, data[0]);
    }
  }, [data, keyVal]);


 return (
  <FormControl color="info" sx={{ minWidth: 100, fontSize: 13 }}  size="small" fullWidth>
   <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
   <Select onChange={(event)=>handleChange(event.target.value)} value={value} disabled={!(data && data?.length > 0)} label={label}>
    {data?.map((d, i) => (
     <MenuItem key={`${keyVal}_${id}_${i}`} value={d}>
      {d}
     </MenuItem>
    ))}
   </Select>

  </FormControl>
 )
}

export default SelectComponent
```

//funtion to set the filters and value

```
 const onChangeVal = (type: string, val: any) => {
  const _filterData = _(sensitivity)
  const { year, Type, Groupings, Region, Type5, Type4, Type3 } = data || {}
  let _filters = {}
  let _unique: null | string = null
  let setItem: any
  switch (type) {
   case "year":
    _unique = "Type"
    setItem = setType
    _filters = isSearch ? { ...data } : { year: val }
    break
   case "Type":
    _unique = "Groupings"
    setItem = setGrouping
    _filters = isSearch ? { ...data } : { year: year, Type: val }
    break
   case "Groupings":
    _unique = "Region"
    setItem = setRegion
    _filters = isSearch ? { ...data } : { year: year, Type: Type, Groupings: val }
    break
   case "Region":
    _unique = "Type5"
    setItem = setType5
    _filters = isSearch ? { ...data } : { year: year, Type: Type, Groupings: Groupings, Region: val }
    break
   case "Type5":
    _unique = "Type4"
    setItem = setType4
    _filters = isSearch ? { ...data } : { year: year, Type: Type, Groupings: Groupings, Region: Region, Type5: val }
    break
   case "Type4":
    _unique = "Type3"
    setItem = setType3
    _filters = isSearch ? { ...data } : { year: year, Type: Type, Groupings: Groupings, Region: Region, Type5: Type5, Type4: val }
    break
   case "Type3":
    _unique = "Type2"
    setItem = setType2
    _filters = isSearch ? { ...data } : { year: year, Type: Type, Groupings: Groupings, Region: Region, Type5: Type5, Type4: Type4, Type3: val }
    break
   case "Type2":
    _filters = isSearch ? { ...data } : { year: year, Type: Type, Groupings: Groupings, Region: Region, Type5: Type5, Type4: Type4, Type3: Type3, Type2: val }
    setIsSearch(false)
    break
   case "Search":
    resetData()
    _filters = { ...val }
    console.log("Search2", _filters)
    setIsSearch(true)
    const _groupData = _filterData.filter(_filters).value()
    console.log("hi search", _groupData)
  }
  if (_unique && typeof setItem === "function") {
   console.log(_unique, setItem)
   const _groupData = _filterData.filter(_filters).uniqBy(_unique).value()
   console.log("_groupData:", _groupData, "setItem:", setItem(_groupData))
   setItem(_groupData)
  } else {
   const _groupData = _filterData.filter(_filters).value()
  }

  setData({ ..._filters })
  console.log("afterfilter", data)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the select component as following

```
import React, { useEffect, useId, useState } from "react"
import _ from "lodash"
import { FormControl, Select, InputLabel, MenuItem, SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material"
import ISelect from "@/types/select"

const SelectComponent: React.FC<ISelect> = (props) => {
const { val, label, keyVal, dataList, onChangeVal,isSearch } = props
 const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>()
 const [value, setVal] = useState<any>("")
 const id = useId()

 useEffect(() => {
 if(val){
 setVal(val)
   console.log(val)
  }

 }, [val])

 useEffect(() => {
   if (keyVal && dataList && dataList?.length > 0) {
     const _data = _.map(dataList, keyVal)
     console.log("data:",_data,"dataList:",dataList,"keyVal:",keyVal,"I ran hhoho")
     setData(_data)
    } else {
      setData([])
    }
  }, [keyVal, dataList])
  
  useEffect(()=>{
   if(val && keyVal && onChangeVal && dataList && dataList.length > 0){
     setVal(val)
     onChangeVal(keyVal,val)
     console.log(val,"I was Called")
   }
  },[val,keyVal])



 const handleChange = (e:string) => {
  const _val = e
  if (keyVal && onChangeVal) {
   setVal(_val)
   onChangeVal(keyVal, _val)
   console.log(dataList)
  }
 }
 useEffect(() => {
    if (keyVal && data && onChangeVal && data.length === 1) {
      setVal(data[0]);
      onChangeVal(keyVal, data[0]);
    }
  }, [data, keyVal]);



 return (
  <FormControl color="info" sx={{ minWidth: 100,  fontSize: 13 }} size="small" fullWidth>
   <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
   <Select onChange={(event)=>handleChange(event.target.value)} value={value} disabled={!(data && data?.length > 0)}  label={label}>
    {data?.map((d, i) => (
     <MenuItem key={`${keyVal}_${id}_${i}`} value={d}>
      {d}
     </MenuItem>
    ))}
   </Select>
  </FormControl>
 )
}

export default SelectComponent
```

and added one more function to set all the data list  all at once.